# Angularjs application with PHP backend not loading on some browsers and devices

Tags: javascript, php, yepnope

My angular.js applications works fine on Windows OS when using Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge.

It fails to load when using Internet Explorer and Safari.

When using macOS, it fails to load when using both Safari and Chrome.

Any idea what could be the cause of this?

I am using a script loader call `yepnope` to load all my JS files.

`yepnope` works like jQuery (ajax). However, in my case, it throws an exception on some browsers and devices.

---

I was able to figure out the answer.

After compiling some of the JS files into a single file, the 'use strict' directive was included in the compiled JS file. This seems to have caused the issue.

Comment: what do you mean by "it fails to load"??whether you cant see anything or something is missing or getting any errors??

Comment: Am using a script loader call yepnope to load all my js files. Yepnope works like jquery (ajax).However, in my case, it throws an exception on some browsers and devices.

Comment: can u update that error in question

Comment: @SaEChowdary just did. Hope that helps to make the question better?
 Any suggestions or ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: that's good and if you can  add that  error content also

Comment: @SaEChowdary I was able to figure out the answer. After compiling some of the js files into a single file, the 'use strict' keyword was included in the compiled js file, therefore causing the issue. 
The 'use strict' keyword, I  think is being handled differently by the various JS engines.Thanks alot

Comment: very nice to hear from you....finally you found your own bug......kudho's and keep it up

Comment: http://jshint.com can be a useful friend for these sorts of things. Will tell you about things like inappropriate use of `use strict'.